# Grabbing SQL records: Nullable bool to bool

Tags: c#, sql, null

So I have a method that does a lookup in an existing `List<T>`, populated elsewhere by grabbing the records from a SQL table holding configuration data for each state where we do business. This method just looks up in the list by state abbreviation and then returns the value of a Boolean field in the record.

```
public bool StateRoundsToQuarterHour(int recordID, string stateAbbrev)
    {
        bool? result = null;

        try
        {
            // Query our existing list of StateConfig objects for a match, then return the value of RoundMinutes.
            result = (from x in listStateConfig
                           where x.State == stateAbbrev
                           select x.RoundMinutes).First();  

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // if state not found, email error and continue
            string strMessage = String.Format("Error: {0} Inner Exception {1}", Convert.ToString(e.Message) + Environment.NewLine, Convert.ToString(e.InnerException));

            // log and email error
            ErrorContinue(recordID, strMessage);

        }

        // as long as we found a result, we're happy
        if(result != null)
        {
            return (bool)result;
        }
        else
        {
            string strMessage = String.Format("State {0} does not exist in table, but RecordID {1} belongs to that state.", stateAbbrev, recordID);

            // log and email error
            ErrorContinue(recordID, strMessage);

            return false;   // if the state doesn't exist, we'll default to rounding is not required
                            // We send an alert about the state not existing, so we'll be able to act on it
        }

    }
```

The List may not contain a result, so in that case the query will not find anything and remain null. I'm not entirely happy with the method using a nullable Boolean internally and then casting it to non-nullable to use in the return, but I don't want the return type of the method to be nullable. Is this a reasonable approach? Where can this be improved?

Comment: Not sure why an editor added "Grabbing SQL records:" to the title? The fact that the data is coming from a SQL table is immaterial.

Comment: Good titles should say (or hint at) what the code does; that addition made your title more specific.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
> // as long as we found a result, we're happy
> if(result != null)
> {
>     return (bool)result;
> }
> ```

This could be written as simply:

```
if (result.HasValue)
{
    return result.Value;
}
```

`bool?` is shorthand for `Nullable<bool>`, a generic *value type* with *reference type* semantics. Basically `Nullable<T>.Value` is a `T`, so there's no need to cast anything.

Also, being a value type, initializing it is redundant.

```
bool? result;
```

Is entirely sufficient.

---

Avoid cluttering your code with comments that don't bring anything to the table:

> ```
> // as long as we found a result, we're happy
> ```

Good comments should say *why* the code does what it does - don't bother commenting just to state the obvious, or to rephrase what the code is already saying.

If this needs a comment every time it's used:

> ```
> // log and email error
> ErrorContinue(recordID, strMessage);
> ```

...then perhaps the `ErrorContinue` method needs a better, more descriptive name?

---

You're catching a `System.Exception` here:

> ```
>     try
>     {
>         // Query our existing list of StateConfig objects for a match, then return the value of RoundMinutes.
>         result = (from x in listStateConfig
>                        where x.State == stateAbbrev
>                        select x.RoundMinutes).First();  
>
>     }
>     catch (Exception e)
>     {
>         //...
>     }
> ```

But it looks like you're only handling the `InvalidOperationException` that `.First()` would throw when there aren't any items matching the `where` criteria.

If the query is meant to return only 1 record, use `.Single()`, not `.First()`. And if the query *can* return no records, use `.SingleOrDefault()`.

The problem is that you're *projecting* the result and `Select`ing `.RoundMinutes`, which is a *value type* and can't be `null`, so `SingleOrDefault()` would return `false` for an `bool` value, because `default(int) == 0`.

You could instead select the actual `StateConfig` object, and boil the code down to this:

```
public bool StateRoundsToQuarterHour(int recordId, string stateAbbrev)
{
    var config = _stateConfig.SingleOrDefault(x => x.State == stateAbbrev);
    if (config != null)
    {
        return config.RoundMinutes;
    }
    else
    {
        var message = string.Format("State '{0}' does not exist in table, but RecordId {1} belongs to that state.", stateAbbrev, recordId);
        _logger.Warn(message);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Notice `Id` vs. `ID`, `_logger.Warn` vs `ErrorContinue`, `message` vs. `strMessage`, and `_stateConfig` vs `listStateConfig`. Don't try to encode the type of a variable into its identifier name, that's bad Hungarian notation, and it's not the type that's useful but what the variable it actually used for.

I'm prefixing private fields (I assumed `listStateConfig` was a private field here) with an underscore, but you could alternatively qualify them with the `this` keyword - that's personal preference.

Comment: Great advice (I have no one to run code by at the office, so I figured I'd give this a try; have never done code reviews... sigh).

Comment: So would a Try...Catch have any benefit in there?

Comment: The best exception handling is writing code that doesn't throw exceptions in the first place. Catching exceptions that can be otherwise avoided, is hurting performance. I don't see any benefit for a try/catch here, no.